How can I transform the evil-ex-history variable to enable the extraction of search and replace strings using mapcar?
When I try to use a mapcar to extract the strings like (mapcar 'car evil-ex-history) it creates an error because of the # character preceding the list.
Copying the expression, deleting the # character and quoting it makes it amenable to mapcar.
How can the transformation be done in a function?
This question https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/11x7gx4/what_do_these_properties_mean_in_the_values_of/ says it is some kind of internal representation used by evil-ex.
Below is a sample of evil-ex-history reduced to 2 entries.
(#("'<,'>s/TODO/NOTE/g" 0 1
   (ex-index 1)
   1 2
   (ex-index 2)
   2 3
   (ex-index 3)
   3 4
   (ex-index 4)
   4 5
   (ex-index 5)
   5 6
   (ex-index 6)
   6 7
   (ex-index 7)
   7 8
   (ex-index 8)
   8 9
   (ex-index 9)
   9 10
   (ex-index 10)
   10 11
   (ex-index 11)
   11 12
   (ex-index 12)
   12 13
   (ex-index 13)
   13 14
   (ex-index 14)
   14 15
   (ex-index 15)
   15 16
   (ex-index 16)
   16 17
   (ex-index 17)
   17 18
   (ex-index 18))
 #("'<,'>s/liblib/lib/g" 0 1
   (ex-index 1)
   1 2
   (ex-index 2)
   2 3
   (ex-index 3)
   3 4
   (ex-index 4)
   4 5
   (ex-index 5)
   5 6
   (ex-index 6)
   6 7
   (ex-index 7)
   7 8
   (ex-index 8)
   8 9
   (ex-index 9)
   9 10
   (ex-index 10)
   10 11
   (ex-index 11)
   11 12
   (ex-index 12)
   12 13
   (ex-index 13)
   13 14
   (ex-index 14)
   14 15
   (ex-index 15)
   15 16
   (ex-index 16)
   16 17
   (ex-index 17)
   17 18
   (ex-index 18)
   18 19
   (ex-index 19)))


It's a list of strings with properties, so you can use substring-no-properties to get just the string:
(mapcar #'substring-no-properties evil-ex-history)

will produce
("'<,'>s/TODO/NOTE/g" "'<,'>s/liblib/lib/g")


in the case above.

Thanks I've had run-ins with substring-no-properties before, but this answer has given me a good starting point for checking them properly.
